# Export Logistic Regression classifier as math formulation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression

I'm training ML models from SKLearn in Python, and sometimes need to export them as text (as mathematical equations).

When doing linear regression it is fairly simple: I take the target's name (`T`), the coefficients (`C1...Cn`), the intercept (`C0`), and the features' names (`A1...An`) to construct a string in the form:

```
T = C0 + C1A1 + C2A2 + ... + CnAn
```

I'm not sure, however, about my implementation for classification algorithms.

For example, let's say I have a Logistic Regression classifier trained to use n features (`A1, ..., An`) to classify between m classes (`T1, ..., Tm`).

If I understand correctly, I can take the coefficients and intercepts from the classifier (`Cij`, with `i=1,2,..,m` and `j=0,1,...,n`) to write the following set:

```
f(T1) = C10 + C11A1 + C12A2 + ... + C1nAn
.
.
.
f(Tm) = Cm0 + Cm1A1 + Cm2A2 + ... + CmnAn
```

Than the class to be picked is the one whose function yields the largest number.

Is this formulation correct?

Comment: Add to that the logistic function (sigmoid). Check the source of LogisticRegression in sklearn.

Comment: I did. It looks like it just picks the class with the highest score, with scores being the dot product of the coefficients and X plus the intercepts. What am I missing? Where does the logistic function comes into play? I guess it's only relevant when using a non default solver? (the default being `liblinear`)

Comment: Yes. Upon further inspection of source code, you are correct about `predict()`. It chooses the class with max value. The sigmoid is only used [calculating probabilities in a binary classification or when `multi-class='ovr'`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py#L1339). It doesnt depend on the solver though.

Comment: I was first thinking that it would call `predict_proba()` which as described above uses the logistic function and then the class with highest probability is chosen. Most examples and implementations of LR follow this approach. But thats not the case with scikit.